# Kohana sessions and database

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I have hard time with kohana sessions, i would like to store my sessions data in database i've already created default `sessions` table, and i have this config file in

```
\application\config\session.php
```

And here is config content: http://pastebin.com/MqqQpH5W

Also my login works just fine, i've tried `var_dump(Auth::instance())` and i see some stuff like `{ ["_session":protected]=> object(Session_Native)#20` so i guess my session does get started, but i'm quite lost on how do i set my session id to the database or some other stuff?
I guess i could just make a normal query for that, but i think there has to be better way to do it.

And btw my main goal is to make list of online users, and i see that i have in table row with name `last_active`, so my guess is that something should update that table automaticaly, right?

**EDIT** So after some googling and search in various files i found out that it loads `native` session type from config file in `application/auth`, so i've tried to change it to `database` and now it keeps putting session data in my database every time i refresh page, and login doesn't work anymore, any sugguestions?

Comment: Having this same exact issue (Kohana 3.1). When I switched from default to DB sessions, login doesn't work, and I see a new session data (row) in the session table every time I do a page refresh (which is not right). I tried suggestions in checked answer but didn't make any difference. Stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kohana 3.2 you do it like this:

Put this in your bootstrap.php file:

```
Session::$default = 'database';
```

And also make sure your cookie configuration is correct. Put this in your bootstrap.php file also

```
Kohana_Cookie::$salt = md5('secret');
Kohana_Cookie::$expiration = 1209600; // 14 days
Kohana_Cookie::$domain = '.yourdomain.com';
```

Where .yourdomain.com will be your host name, make sure you put a dot (.) before it so it will include sub-domains too.

Comment: That's strange if i put `Session::$default = 'database'` into bootstrap i get blank page, no html no erros nothing at all

Comment: Try enabling error reporting to see if it throws back any errors.

Comment: Is this the equivalent of or an addition to the "session adapter settings" described in the Kohana docs: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/sessions#session-adapter-settings?